# Storing arbitrary object inside a field with meteor simple schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I have a schema with a field `type: Object` . But whenever i do an insert, that object is empty.

Here is my schema

```
Contacts.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,

    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    twitterFriend: { // this field
        type: Object,
        optional: true
    }
}));
```

Even if do `Contacts.insert({firstName: 'Mustafa', twitterFriend: {test: 'this should be stored'}})` . It does not work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For an object of arbitrary sub-schema you set `blackbox: true`

```
Contacts.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,

    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    twitterFriend: { // this field
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    }
}));
```

See SimpleSchema [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#blackbox) for reference.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work at all, it's like SimpleSchema just ignores blackbox?

Comment: @Jan You might have to post your code in another question, then link us to it. Maybe something else is slightly off?